# Can one travel from Jeju island to Seoul without a passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, south-korea, jeju

A friend of mine misplaced his passport while staying in Jeju island. Normally I would advise him to just travel to Seoul, get an emergency passport from his embassy and fly back home without issues, but I know that Jeju island has a special immigration regime.

Are there any immigration checks on the way from Jeju island to Seoul? If not, can one travel that route without a passport?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need an ID for domestic flights. They need an ID to pass through security, and those who are not authorized to visit the mainland will be turned back (at Security or check-in).

Accepted IDs: ([source, Korean](http://www.airport.co.kr/www/bbs/boardView.do?id=1&menuId=351&bIdx=3541950&page=1))

1. Passport
2. International Driving Permit
3. Alien Registration Card
4. Korean Permanent Resident Card
5. ID for US Army in Korea

Comment: If IDP works then that's fine :)

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on whether they would need a visa (but didn't for Jeju)?

Comment: @Giorgio Uhm yes, I am assuming they have right to enter the mainland - otherwise, they can't pass thru the security anyway.

Comment: That's what I mean: there are nationals who can visit Jeju visa free, but require a visa for the Republic of Korea. You could note that in your answer.

Comment: @revi so there is in fact an immigration check?

Comment: @JonathanReez - yeah, looks like they do have immigration check according to some sources, except they don't state if that's done at security or checkin. ([source](https://namu.wiki/w/%EC%A0%9C%EC%A3%BC%EA%B5%AD%EC%A0%9C%EA%B3%B5%ED%95%AD#s-3) just says they have different lanes for Koreans and non-Koreans) Sorry about this.

Comment: @revi, As someone who flew from Jeju to mainland Korea, my experience was that they checked passports before security check. That wasn't a full-fledged passport control, they merely looked at one's passport and checked identity. The whole procedure took a few seconds.

Comment: @revi So Korean citizens need a passport?

Comment: You can use it as a proof of identity, but you're not required to (specifically) have passport.